# Show a Powerpoint Presentation in a Frame in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, overlay, powerpoint

What I try to achieve is to show a PowerPoint Presentation directly without opening Powerpoint beforhand in a WPF Window. 
Right now I'm using this code to start the Presentation:

```
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\POWERPNT.EXE";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " /s " + source.ToString();
    proc.Start();
```

with the variable source being the path to the desired file.
This Code opens the PowerPoint Presentation in Fullscreen, which would be fine, but my Application is running on a Touch Device with no Keyboard or Mouse connected. So I would like to be able to put a overlay above the presentation itself with a "Close"-Button for example.

I already found this topic
[Hosting external app in WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028598/hosting-external-app-in-wpf-window), but I'm having a hard time understanding what's actually going on there.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094792/convert-selected-powerpoint-shapes-or-drawingml-to-xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it in a way I'm comfortable with.
Here is the Code:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="Project.PowerPointViewer"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="PowerPointViewer" Background="Transparent" Topmost="True" AllowsTransparency="True" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized">
```

The important part being: Background, Topmost and AllowTransparency

Code Behind:

```
public partial class PowerPointViewer : Window
{
    Process proc = new Process();
    Window main;
    public PowerPointViewer(Window main)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.main = main;
    }

    public void open(string source)
    {
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\POWERPNT.EXE";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " /s " + source;
        proc.Start();
        Show();
    }

    private void bt_close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!proc.HasExited)
            proc.Kill();
        Close();
        main.Focus();
    }
}
```